# recursive method that checks if arraylist elements are nondecreasing

Tags: java, recursion

I'm getting a stackoverflow error on my method and I'm not sure why because my

`if (index < elements.size())`

line makes sure that it's not an infinite recursive call. This is my code so far.

```
 private boolean checkIfIncreasing(ArrayList<T> elements, int index){ 
  index = 0;
  boolean currentReturnVal = false; 

  //element at position 0 of the passed in array 
  T objAtIndex = elements.get(index); 

  //element at position 1 of the passed in array 
  T objAtNextIndex = elements.get(index + 1);

  //if the size is 1 then just return true bc its the only element in there 
  if (elements.size() == 1){ currentReturnVal = true;}

  if (index < elements.size()){ //takes care of non infinite "looping"

     //checks to see if obj at index 0 is less than or equal to obj 1
     if (objAtIndex.compareTo(objAtNextIndex) <= 0){ 
        currentReturnVal = true;}

     checkIfIncreasing(elements, index++);
     if (objAtIndex.compareTo(objAtNextIndex) >= 0){ 
        return false; } 
  }
  return currentReturnVal;
 }
```

I don't know why i'm receiving the error

Comment: index = 0; - you are resetting your recursion variable in each method invocation.

Comment: You're also ignoring the result of the recursive call to checkIfIncreasing.

Comment: if i remove the 0 its still the same error... @MGorgon

Comment: @JBNizet how do i unignore it? I'm sorry I'm new to recursion.

Comment: you need to exit your function without invoking another recursion

Comment: @MGorgon and how would I do that?

Comment: I hope you realize that non-decreasing != increasing.  Either your subject line is misleading, or your method name is.